# Аэропорт Заводское в Симферополе. Название аэропорта кавычится?

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Аэропорт Заводское есть в Симферополе. Название аэропорта кавычится? Оно не дублирует никакого географического местонахождения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Из ответа на аналогичный вопрос справочной службы [**Грамоты.ру:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=291613)

> Названия аэропортов справочные пособия рекомендуют писать без кавычек.

Comment: т.е любых?....их данного аэропорта только кукурузники летают....

Comment: А какая разница, кто летает?

Answer (score 1):

Если аэропорт имеет название, то оно пишется без кавычек (как административная единица):

Дополнительную экономию компаниям и резерв для снижения тарифов даст и новый бюджетный **аэропорт Ермолино** в Калужской области.

При этом **аэропорт Кольцово** в Екатеринбурге сейчас одна из самых динамично развивающихся воздушных гаваней страны.

Международный **аэропорт Басры** похож на осажденную крепость ― он окружен бетонными блоками, колючей проволокой и пулеметными дотами.

На строительство третьей взлетно-посадочной полосы претендует и **аэропорт Шереметьево.**

**Иногда аэропорты не имеют собственного названия:**

К примеру, авиакомпания перестала летать в новый аэропорт Горно-Алтайска. Уже сейчас аэропорт Симферополя ежедневно принимает и отправляет по сто рейсов.

Answer (score 0):

К дополнению к ответу slava1947

Названия аэропортов справочные пособия рекомендуют писать без кавычек, *однако за последние годы наблюдается устойчивая тенденция заключать эти наименования в кавычки. Возможно, скоро такое написание будет признано нормативным*. **Однако сейчас лучше писать без кавычек: аэропорты Шереметьево, Домодедово, Пулково, Борисполь.**

[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)